Updating header options in setOptions not working
I am trying to update the headerTintColor of a header if the scrollY position is more than 0. I am using react-native-reanimated for the animation. However, my color is not getting updated.
const header = useSharedValue(false);

const onScroll = useAnimatedScrollHandler((event) => {
  scrollY.value = event.contentOffset.y;
  header.value = event.contentOffset.y > 0;
  console.log(header.value); // correct true and false value here
}, []);

const getHeaderTintColor = useMemo(() => {
  return header.value ? "red" : "blue";
}, [header.value]);

useEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerTintColor: getHeaderTintColor,
    headerRight: () => (
      <VenueButtons
        sharePress={handleSharePress}
        favouritePress={() => handleFavouritePress()}
        isFavourite={isFavourite}
      />
    ),
  });
}, [loading, navigation, isFavourite, handleFavouritePress, getHeaderTintColor, header]);


Use onScroll to detect scroll position. Something like this:
const [color, setColor] = useState('black');

useEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({ headerTintColor: color });
}, [navigation, color]);

return (
  <ScrollView
    onScroll={({
      nativeEvent: {
        contentOffset: { y },
      },
    }) => {
      setColor(y > 0 ? 'red' : 'black');
    }}>
...
  </ScrollView>
);

